# ASP.NET Core Mimal APIs - AddEndpointFilter throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

`AddEndpointFilter` throws exception shown below in .NET 7 (7.0.102) at program start under debug. Used IDE Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.6.3

```
System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=A suitable constructor for type 'WebApplication3.OperationCancelledFilter' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and all parameters of a public constructor are either registered as services or passed as arguments. Also ensure no extraneous arguments are provided.
Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions
StackTrace:
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.FindApplicableConstructor(Type instanceType, Type\[\] argumentTypes, ConstructorInfo& matchingConstructor, Nullable\`1\[\]& matchingParameterMap) in /_/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/src/ActivatorUtilities.cs:line 216
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(Type instanceType, Type\[\] argumentTypes) in /_/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/src/ActivatorUtilities.cs:line 97
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.EndpointFilterExtensions.AddEndpointFilter\[TBuilder,TFilterType\](TBuilder builder)
```

[Unhandled exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJoNl.png)

This is full code example.

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app
    .MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!")
    .AddEndpointFilter<OperationCancelledFilter>();

app.Run();

class OperationCancelledFilter : IEndpointFilter
{
    private readonly ILogger<OperationCancelledFilter> _logger;

    public OperationCancelledFilter(
        ILogger<OperationCancelledFilter> logger
        )
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async ValueTask<object?> InvokeAsync(EndpointFilterInvocationContext context, EndpointFilterDelegate next)
    {
        try
        {
            return await next(context);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug(ex, "Request was cancelled");

            return Results.StatusCode(499);
        }
    }
}
```

If I click on continue application starts OK and breakpoint is hit so it works. Only problem is during startup with unhandled exception.

It works in this way without any unandled exception.

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app
    .MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!")
    .AddEndpointFilter(async (context, next) =>
    {
        var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger("program");

        try
        {
            return await next(context);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            logger.LogDebug(ex, "Request was cancelled");

            return Results.StatusCode(499);
        }
    });

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I deleted constructor at all and unhandled exception is still there.

```cs
class OperationCancelledFilter : IEndpointFilter
{
    public async ValueTask<object?> InvokeAsync(EndpointFilterInvocationContext context, EndpointFilterDelegate next)
    {
        try
        {
            return await next(context);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {

            return Results.StatusCode(499);
        }
    }
}
```

Project is default ASP.NET Core created from empty template.

```json
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

**UPD**

Problem was solved by clearing Visual Studio Symbols cache under Options -> Debugging -> Symbols

Comment: 1. please do not post extra info as answer 2. How do you actually run the project? Have you tried rebuilding and restarting?

Comment: OK, next time I will edit my original post instead ;) I run project in debug mode in Visual Studio 2022. If I run it in command line using `dotnet run` there is no unhandled exception. Even in VS Code it runs without any issue.

Comment: Wow I have just deleted Symbols cache directory in Visual Studio and now it runs in debug without any unhandled exception at startup.

Comment: have you tried cleaning and then rebuilding the project? If it does not help, delete bin and obj folders and build again. And restart VS.

Comment: @guru-stron Yeah without no effect. As I posted above. Deleting Symbols cache directory in Visual Studio solves this isues.

Comment: feel free to update answer to reflect the solution.

Comment: @beda: Could you edit out your original text, and just show what solved the problem? Answers should be focused on the solution.